# Razor Page Net Core 2.0 - Preserve Data after Post

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0, razorengine, razor-pages

I'm banging my head trying to figure this out it should be simple...

I want to get a List of all Users, select one in a <.select>, press a button, get all roles this user has assigned and that's where it fails here's the code

```
    public class RoleManagementModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

        public RoleManagementModel(RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager,
                                    UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }

        [BindProperty]
        public InputModel Input { get; set; }

        public IList<ApplicationUser> UserList { get; set; }
        public IList<string> UserRoleList { get; set; } 
        public IList<string> RoleList { get; set; } 

        public class InputModel
        {
            public string User { get; set; }
            public string RoleToRemove { get; set; }
            public string RoleToAdd { get; set; }
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
        {
            UserList = _userManager.Users.ToList();
            UserRoleList = new List<string>();
            RoleList = new List<string>();
            return Page();
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostGetRolesAsync()
        {
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.User);
            UserRoleList =  await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            return Page();
        }
    }
```

This is the Razor Page

```
        <select asp-for="Input.User" class="..">
            @foreach (ApplicationUser au in Model.UserList)
            {
                <option>@au.UserName</option>
            }
        </select>

    <button class=".." type="submit" asp-page-handler="GetRoles">Get Roles </button>

    <select asp-for="Input.RoleToRemove" class="..">
         @foreach (string ur in Model.UserRoleList)
         {
            <option>@ur</option>
         }
    </select>
```

I've tried the following:

return `Page()` after `OnPostGetRolesAsync()` throws an exception

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

`@foreach (ApplicationUser au in Model.UserList)`

I guess because the `OnGet` is not run and the `UserList` is `null`

If i change it to `RedirectToPage()` then `OnGet` gets fired and sets UserRoleList to a new List and we're back to square one

Removing `UserRoleList = new List<string>();`
from `OnGet` will throw same exception(but for UserRoleList) when trying to open the page

cheers

Comment: use tempdata is a better option i think

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You load the UserList in Get but you have to load it again for the post request

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync()
    {
        UserList = _userManager.Users.ToList();
        UserRoleList = new List<string>();
        RoleList = new List<string>();
        return Page();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostGetRolesAsync()
    {
        UserList = _userManager.Users.ToList();     // You have to reload

        var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.User);
        UserRoleList =  await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
        return Page();
    }
```

Comment: Works like a charm, i combined it with TempData to reduce DB Queries. Cheers!